# How can I download files from team drives?

Tags: python, pydrive

I'd like to periodically download and upload a file from a shared teams drive on google drive. I can upload to the folder, but not download.

This is what I've tried

```
team_drive_id = 'YYY'
file_to_download= 'ZZZ'
parent_folder_id = 'XXX'

f = drive.CreateFile({
        'id':file_to_download,
        'parents': [{
        'kind': 'drive#fileLink',
        'teamDriveId': team_folder_id,
        'id': parent_drive_id
    }]
})
f= drive.CreateFile({'id': file_to_download})
f.GetContentFile('test.csv', mimetype='text/csv')
```

But this is what I get:

```
ApiRequestError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/file_to_download?alt=json returned "File not found: file_to_download">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the file with the path `test.csv` is correct and the file exists. Because this is what the error says

Comment: My path was wrong, thanks for the help @UliSotschok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the documentation that can be seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/)

First you create the file:

```
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_to_download})
```

then you set the content on the file

```
f.SetContentString("whatever comes inside this file, it is a csv so you know what to expect to be here")
```

and to finish the upload you need to do

```
f.Upload()
```

after that, the file is properly created there, you can read it using the `GetContentString` method

Comment: This only works when you are creating and downloading the file in the same session. If I try to come back later on, it is unable to find the file, or if I create another CreateFile instance using the newly generated ID, it returns a 404 file not found.